# Having trouble creating onHover on Grid item component MaterialUI

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, hover

I am creating a Grid layout that has nested Grid components in it. However, for some reason I do not understand, using an inline style in the Grid item component does not work. Please help, I am quite new in using MaterialUI in ReactJS. The Grid is encapsulated inside a Hide component that only shows in mobile devices.

> What I am trying to achieve is that the Grid item change color on
> hover

Here is what I did:

```
<Hidden mdUp='hide'>
          <Grid
            container
            xs={12}
            style={{
              fontFamily: 'Old Newspaper',
              background: '#f49275',
              '&:hover': { background: 'black' },
              marginLeft: '4px',
              marginRight: '4px',
            }}
          >
            <Grid
              item
              xs={4}
              style={{
                justifyContent: 'center',
                display: 'flex',
              }}
            >
              <a href='#'>
                &diams; Github &diams;
              </a>
            </Grid>
            <Grid
              item
              xs={4}
              style={{ justifyContent: 'center', display: 'flex' }}
            >
              <a
                href='#'
                target='_blank'
              >
                &diams; LinkedIn &diams;
              </a>
            </Grid>
            <Grid
              item
              xs={4}
              style={{ justifyContent: 'center', display: 'flex' }}
            >
              <a
                href='#'
                target='_blank'
              >
                &diams; Codewars &diams;
              </a>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </Hidden>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get hover style on grid items you've to add hover style on grid items. And you can't add hover styles on an element in inline CSS way. Give a className to grid items and then add hover styles on those.

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import { Hidden } from "@material-ui/core";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  item:{
    color:'#fff',
    justifyContent: "center",
    display: "flex",
    '&:hover':{
      '&>a':{
        color:'green'
      }
    }
  }
}));

export default function SpacingGrid() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  
  return (
    <Hidden mdUp="hide">
      <Grid
        container
        className={classes.container}
        xs={12}
        style={{
          fontFamily: "Old Newspaper",
          background: "#f49275",
          marginLeft: "4px",
          marginRight: "4px"
        }}
      >
        <Grid
          item
          xs={4}
          className={classes.item}
        >
          <a href="#">&diams; Github &diams;</a>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={4} className={classes.item}>
          <a href="#" target="_blank">
            &diams; LinkedIn &diams;
          </a>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={4} className={classes.item}>
          <a href="#" target="_blank">
            &diams; Codewars &diams;
          </a>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </Hidden>
  );
}
```

codesandbox link:- https://codesandbox.io/s/o8b52

And can you please elaborate more your doubt about using inline style in grid item.